# How to reduce white line space in widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, spacing

I have a wordpress blog and by default there is basically double spacing between every line, leaving a white space, on the text widget.  This has something with the theme, and after spending some time going through the coding I was unable to find it (I'm extremely new to coding and have been teaching myself...

Anyways, even using html codes to try and reduce the space have not really helped.  Here is an image of the text widget that I'm talking about:
[Image](http://postimage.org/image/6s515ve6z/)

And also, here's a link to my site [tradingliberation.com](http://tradingliberation.com). You can see the widget on the right side of the screen, with the label "Key Data Calendar."

Again, please keep in mind I know pretty much nothing when it comes to coding.  Sorry for the ignorance and thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, it seems that the result of your vertical spacing is [`line-height` CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) :
(line 755 in style.css)

```
#sidebar ul {
    line-height: 24px;
...
```

To set line-height for just this small part of your sidebar, you can wrap the content in a div tag, to which you apply a desired line-height.

However, you shouldn't define line-height in pixels. [Percentage value or EMs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) would be a better idea. In this case, you'd just change it to `line-height: 150%;`

To troubleshot this kind of problems you should use some kind of Web Developer tool. For Firefox, there's a native one, or Firebug extension. For Google Chrome and IE it's the built-in Code Inspector. You can switch them on by pressing F12 in the browser window.

Comment: thank you for your help, I ended up just changing the line-height in the CSS file cause I never did like that amount of space.  Thanks again!